# Django related_name not querying the data in template

Tags: django

I have two models, Transaction and Subscription. Transaction has a FK to Subscription with the related name="subscription_transaction". I am trying to query the transaction.amount on a SubscriptionDetailView. Why is my template query not working.

Neither work

**subscription_detail.html**

```
<td  class="text-dark ">{{ subscription.subscription_transaction.timestamp.all }}</td
<td  class="text-dark"> {{ subscription.subscription_transaction.amount }}</td>`
```

**models.py**

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user_membership = models.ForeignKey(UserMembership, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_membership.user.username

    @property
    def get_created_date(self):
        subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(self.stripe_subscription_id)
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(subscription.created)

    @property
    def get_next_billing_date(self):
        subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(self.stripe_subscription_id)
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(subscription.current_period_end)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_transaction")
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="subscription_transaction")
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    success = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

Comment: `subscription.subscription_transaction` is a `RelatedManager` object.

Comment: If you want a subscription to be linked with one transaction, then use `OneToOneField`. In that case, the template you have will work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `subscription.subscription_transaction` is a `RelatedManager` object, you can get all transactions of the subscription using `.all`.

**Example**:

```
{% for transaction in subscription.subscription_transaction.all %}
    Timestamp: {{ transaction.timestamp }}, 
    Amount: {{ transaction.amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `Transaction` has a `ForeignKey` to `Subscription`. That's a one to many relation: Each `Transaction` row can have up to one `Subscription` however each `Subscription` can be related with many `Transactions`.

Following this you should now understand that you are able to use the direct relation betwen `Transaction` and `Subscription` (i.e from a `Transaction` instance) directly, i.e you can do something like `transaction.subscription.active` sincec each transaction will have one subscription. However, to use the reverse relation (i.e from `Subscription`) you need to properly use the related object manager to enumerate all possible transactions the subscription may have. Remember that Django auto-names the reverse relation object `something_set` (in your case instead of `subscription_transaction` you'd have a `transaction_set` attribute to the `Subscription` instance); there's a reason for that: To remember that the reverse relation of a foreign key is a set of objects!

Thus, if you change your template code to something like:

```
{% for tr in subscription.subscription_transaction.all %}
  {{ tr.timestamp }}
  {{ tr.amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

it will output all the transactions of the subscription.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaination, I understand now! I would have given you the green check, but your last line is incorrect. It's endfor

Comment: You're welcome! I also fixed the error with the last line.